# Looking for a formal equivalent phrase for “the above”

Tags: synonyms

I like to know a formal equivalent phrase for "the above". I'm writing a scientific paper, and someone told me that phrase is not correct for a scientific paper.

An example is the following.

"Taking into account the above, the new formula is better than the other one."

Comment: Was the reason 'someone' gave lack of formality or lack of specificness? Did they point you to a style guide supporting their view? 'The above' is far from informal.

Answer (score 2):

**Aforementioned**/**Aforestated**

You could write,

> Taking into account the aforementioned text/statement, the new formula is better than the other one.

You may like to check out the [Thesaurus link](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/aforementioned).

Comment: It's subjective, but I am a fan of using "the aforementioned" by itself, without using "text/statement". Of course, this only applies in cases where it is obvious what I'm trying to reference, usually when it _directly_ follows the thing I'm referencing.

Comment: If you see the edit history, even I put [text] in brackets, making it optional. However, as the requirement of the OP is for a scientific paper, you wouldn't want anything left to speculation, howsoever obvious. Good remark though, @Flater.

Comment: Hadn't seen the history, it's not really a reflex to check it :)